# window load function happening too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, load

I'm attempting call a function that sets the height of an element based on the current height of its parent element when the window completes loading.

However, the facebook comment iframe is not being taken into consideration with...

```
$(window).load(function() {
    columnHeight();
});
```

Any ideas how to handle the window.load function when iframes exist within the page?  I want to be sure that the columnHeight() is passed once **everything** is fully loaded.

**Example of Issue:**

- http://squeebles.com/i-have-never-seen-anything-like-this-chinchilla-total-must-watch/

**Reproduction steps:**

- Go to URL above
- Quickly scroll to the bottom of the page
- Notice the left sidebar properly sized to match the height of the body
- Watch the Facebook comment system load and cause the left side bar to no longer match the height of the body wrapper

Comment: Why not just use CSS for the height? Is there a reason it needs to be done with script?

Comment: The height will never be one consistent value.  It should always adjust itself to the parent height (div#wrapper).

Comment: You could try using the [faux columns method](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns). Basically a vertically repeating image that contains both "column" backgrounds, and the content is just floated on top to give the appearance of columns.

Comment: `$(window).load()` only waits until content specified in the actual HTML of the page finishes loading.  It does not wait for content that might be loaded by scripts or ajax calls to load.  By looking at your page, it appears that this content is being loaded dynamically by facebook code.  Probably what you need is a Facebook event when IT has finished loading its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(window).load()` waits for the content directly specified in the HTML of the page to be loaded.

It does not wait for iframes to be loaded.  It does not wait for content that might be created or loaded by scripts or ajax calls to be finished.

The Facebook content in the page you reference appears to be loaded dynamically by Facebook scripts so if you want to know precisely when that is done, you will need to find a Facebook event in the Facebook API that notifies you when it's done.  The Facebook events API is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/.

It looks to me like this might be what you need, but you would have to test it in your page to be sure:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

You also may need to wait until the Facebook API itself is loaded before you can call this.

Comment: Hrmp, I could of sworn that the .load() waits till everything within the primary window (including additional windows (iframes)) to load before it's fired.  How does one write something to wait for all iframes to load before firing? (not a JS developer, so be easy please).

Comment: @JoeyO'Driscoll - rewrote my answer after looking at the content in your referenced page.

Comment: It worked the first time, but seems to be a bit temperamental.  I'll continue researching the JavaScript reference doc for FB! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

maybe here is a problem with css specificity

use the method css() + !important

Comment: Two things (1) I never use !important within CSS as I've been taught it is bad habit (2) Setting the value to !important will not fix the issue I'm having.